# Removing a created javascript fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found online a [function](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/) that on click it would add some input and a link. This link, when clicked should remove the created input.

The thing is, I use fieldsets and although I can create the new inputs I can't delete them if wanted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
            $('<p><fieldset class="form-group input-group-sm col-md-4"><label for="formGroupExampleInput">Title</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" style="max-width: 100px;" placeholder="e.g. Day 1" /></fieldset><fieldset class="form-group input-group-sm col-md-8"><label for="formGroupExampleInput">Artists</label><inputtype="text" class="form-control" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" style="max-width: 250px;" placeholder="e.g. AC/DC, Guns and Roses" /></fieldset><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
                $(this).parent().remove();
            return false;
    });
});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: what error you getting when try to remove ?

Comment: I've retagged your question since you appear to be using jQuery (little detail you forgot to mention). If you happen to be using a different library that shares a similar syntax please fix my edit.

Comment: Gokul Shinde I'm not getting any error, it simply doesn't delete the thing I created.
Álvaro González sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the button click listener inside for loop.

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').bind('click', function() {
            //$().appendTo(scntDiv);
            console.log(i)
            $('<p id="newp'+i+'"></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            var html = '<fieldset class="form-group input-group-sm col-md-4"><label for="formGroupExampleInput">Title</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" style="max-width: 100px;" placeholder="e.g. Day 1" /></fieldset><fieldset class="form-group input-group-sm col-md-8"><label for="formGroupExampleInput">Artists</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" style="max-width: 250px;" placeholder="e.g. AC/DC, Guns and Roses" /></fieldset><a href="#" id="remScnt' + i +'">Remove</a>';
             var succss = $("#newp"+i).append(html)
             console.log(succss)
            $('#remScnt'+ i ).on('click', function() {
                console.log($(this).parent())
                $(this).parent().remove();
                   return false;
            });
            i++;
            return false;
    });


});
```

Here is the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4p2o9he9/13/

Comment: I managed to put it working but it deletes every single one that it's created not only 1 and doesn't allow me to create new ones unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because #remScnt doesn't exist when you're binding the click handler:

```
$('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
.. stuff
});
```

You can use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#remScnt', function () {
.. stuff
});
```

[See Direct and Delegated Events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I have two inputs as I click to add more it creates 2 more fields but now that I changed to the delegated event handler when I click to remove, it removes all of them and for some reason I can't add any again, unless I refresh the page.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you are creating links with the same id this is the first problem. It will be better for the remove link to use class instead of id. Also you should address it like this `$(document).on("click", "remScnt", function(){})` the other is fine.

Also it is a good practice to insert scripts inside `$(document).on("ready", function(){ //Your script in here});` So all events are added once the page is fully loaded.

Comment: I've done what you said and some other people answered here and now I can remove, the problem is it deletes every single one that is created and and doesn't allow me to create new ones unless I refresh the page